# App crash due to SIGTRAP, while executing libc.so code

Tags: c, linux

I see this issue intermittently when running my App.

The Application crashes with the message

```
6 APP.BIN[5959]: unhandled signal 5 at 0ee786f8
```

When I checked the stack trace which leads to the crash it points to `clock_gettime()` call.

The call is made periodically to do some monitoring tasks.

I DO NOT any have gdb / debugger running, the code is built with `-g -ggdb` flags and `-O` optimization

```
# cat /proc/75/maps 

0edb6000-0ee59000 r-xp 00000000 01:00 4222       /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
0ee59000-0ee74000 ---p 001a3000 01:00 4222       /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
0ee74000-0ee76000 r--p 001ae000 01:00 4222       /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so
0ee76000-0ee79000 rwxp 001b0000 01:00 4222       /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so   <<< 0ee786f8
```

Looking at the faulting address, its from libc.so

I am on PPC 476 core (32bit embedded processor) using RHEL 7.1 OS

**Question :**

My understanding - `SIGTRAP` is used when running under a debugger, in my case, I am NOT doing that.

Why is `SIGTRAP` triggered when `clock_gettime()` call is made and what makes this issue intermittent?

I do see this problem when I actually attach gdb to my app and try to single step.

Does this intermittent issue of `SIGTRAP` be due to some run time issue? like memory corruption?

I can ignore the signal by `signal(SIGTRAP, SIG_IGN)` but don't want to try that.

Please help in understanding the background for this issue.

Comment: Bad memory can indeed cause an issue like this, especially when it only occurs sporadically. There is a tool called "memtester", which tries to detect bad memory in the running system, might be worth a try.

Comment: You probably make something very wrong like corrupt your memory in some way. Did you tried valgrind or any other testing/verifying tool on your code?

Comment: It would be handy to see small piece of code that reproduces the problem. Also, what platform/architecture/Linux distro are you using?

Comment: SIGTRAP most likely means your code has hit the breakpoint instruction, which usually means it has jumped where it shouldn't, which in turn probably means a return address somewhere in the call stack gets overwritten.

Comment: Hi All, 
Thanks for the inputs, the issue is seen on ppc 32 core using RHEL 7.1 as OS. Its an embedded environment, I will try to check the support for memtester and valgrind and use them to detect memory corruption. 

I did try to reproduce the problem as a standalone , no luck so far.

I will get back once i have more updates.

Comment: sometimes glibc, raises sigtrap, in case of assertion, maybe your libc reached some kind of  __assert_fail